# ModelSIM not generating outputs for any variables

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I have been working on this issue for days and have not been able to figure it out. I was hoping one of you could help me solve this issue.

So, when I run my SV code in Quartus and compile it, I don't receive any errors. This also happens when I compile my code in ModelSIM. However, whenever I generate my waveform analysis in ModelSIM, none of the variables, except for the ones that I force, are changing their values.

Code is below:

Top_level.sv

```
module top_level (
    input logic SYS_CLK,
    input logic PS2_CLK,
    input logic PS2_DATA,
    input logic rst,
    output logic [3:0] VGA_R, VGA_G, VGA_B,
    output logic h_sync_o, v_sync_o  // h_sync and vertical sync output
);

logic reducedClk; 
logic halfClock;
logic [1:0] direction = 0;
logic [9:0] x = 0, y = 0;

halfClk half (
    .clk(SYS_CLK),
    .reset(rst),
    .halfclk(halfClock)
);
counter count (
    .SYS_CLK(SYS_CLK),
    .reset(rst),
    .newCLK(reducedClk)
);
```

halfClk.sv

```
module halfClk(input logic clk, input logic reset, output logic halfclk);   // This module takes in a clock signal, and outputs a clock signal with half the frequncy
    always_ff@(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset)
            halfclk <= 0;                                                       // at every single positive edge of the clock,
        halfclk = ~halfclk; 
    end                                                         // the slow clock flips. This means that for each two cycles of the clock, the half clock is cycled. 
endmodule                                                                           //this produces a duty cycle of 50%
```

counter.sv

```
module counter (
    input logic SYS_CLK,
    input logic reset,
    output logic newCLK
);

logic [11:0] CLK_COUNTER;

always_ff @(posedge SYS_CLK) begin  
    if (reset) begin
        CLK_COUNTER <= 0;
        newCLK <= 1;
    end     
    if (CLK_COUNTER < 2000) begin
        CLK_COUNTER <= CLK_COUNTER + 1;
        newCLK <= newCLK;
    end
    else begin
        CLK_COUNTER <= 0;
        newCLK <= ~newCLK;
    end
end 
endmodule
```

For the purposes of this question, ignore all the other variables. I think that if you can help me figure out why `halfClock` and `reducedClock` are not changing, it will help me with the other ones.

ModelSIM[image: ModelSIM wave]

Thank You for your help in advance, this bug has really been annoying.

Comment: adding a reset to counter and halfClk still doesn't change the outputs of reducedClk and halfClock in ModelSIM

Comment: Your counter has been described with a synchronous reset, so reset must be asserted in your tb during a posedge of SYS_CLK. Also you need to wrap the remaining code after the reset block in another block " if (reset) begin ... end else begin ... end "

Answer (score 0):

You need a synchronous reset in order for the register to initialize to 0, and then start counting.